# How do you trust two different cloud provider servers?

Tags: encryption, linux, public-key-infrastructure, confidentiality

I've found a question with an answer here on Security StackExchange or on Unix StackExchange, but I can't find it anymore apparently :( If you find this answer already, help would be appreciated, I already searched both places extensively.

What I want to achieve is to have two different cloud providers and have the encryption key locally on my machine and have the file system of the other server mounted ENCRYPTED and for it to be secure. I know there's been an answer for this somewhere but I can't find it anymore. It contained something with mounting with `encfs`, `cryfs` or similar. The only requirements are for it to be secure and that the other server gets mounted with an encryption layer (encrypted on transit & encrypted at rest).

- What would be the most secure method for this?
- As an alternative: what would be the most secure method if one of the cloud servers is trusted and the other one is just used for **encrypted-only** storage? By that I mean only encrypted data goes in and comes out of the storage server.

I found a good `sshfs` guide here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62682

But I need to somehow to combine it with `cryfs`, `encfs` or similar (the best option)

Comment: You might be looking for some combination of s3fs (to mount the cloud file storage in your local file system) + encfs (to add an encryption layer over the mounted file storage).  See https://www.emcken.dk/work/linux/2010/12/01/storing-encrypted-data-in-amazon-s3/.  This article is dated, but maybe it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @mti2935 would switching out `encfs` with `cryfs` be a good solution? also I don't need `s3fs` I guess, since I'm not using S3, what should I use instead? sshfs + cryfs?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  It's been a while since I played with this.

Comment: *" ...two different cloud providers ... my machine ... the other server"* - I'm not fully sure about what you exactly refer to here. Do you mean that you have *two servers*, each with a different cloud provider and that "my machine" is one of these servers and "the other server" the other one (at the different provider)? And couldn't the question simplified to just asking on how to keep the encryption key for a file system remote and load it only from remote when mounting the file system?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich sorry for the confusion. The main scenario would be two servers, which I don't trust and they have to have encryption to make up some trust. The second alternative scenario is that I trust one server or PC and I want to host my data on this remote server, which would probably be equal to encrypting files on Dropbox/GDrive/OneDrive etc. The key on the local machine is only decrypting and only in that case. If you find my question confusing feel free to edit accordingly.

Comment: *"two servers, which I don't trust  and they have to have encryption to make up some trust."* - how does encryption of data on the server adds trust to a server? And why you consider two servers in this scenario instead of one, i.e. how is the number of servers important? *"If you find my question confusing feel free to edit accordingly."* - I'm still too confused to be able to edit. If there are multiple scenarios then please clearly distinguish between these instead of merging all into one sentence. I.e. describe what you have and what you want to achieve for each separately.

Comment: I meant that two untrusted environments should create one trusted connection, that is possibly? I just tried it out using mounting first with `sshfs` and `cryfs` then afterwards and an answer will follow once I benchmarked the whole connection speed etc

Comment: @SirMuffington: Maybe I understood your question completely wrong. Lets try again: you want to store your files remotely (as backup or whatever) but don't trust the remote server. Therefore you want to use client side encryption. And for better availability you want to have multiple servers - all containing the same (encrypted) data. Did I get it right? In this case the title *"How do you trust two different cloud provider servers?"* would not fit though since you don't need to trust the remote servers.

Comment: I will try to answer your questions this way: I have Server A and B which I don't really trust that. Since I don't trust both of them the key should NOT be stored on either server A or B. If I remotely mount server's B storage via `sshfs` for example and then encrypt it by locally mounting via `cryfs` locally I get an encryption layer and both servers are not trusted per se, but encryption "adds" some trust, because from the perspective from the PC named C the files ARE secure. I hope this clarifies it up. And yes I think you will need to trust one server A in this case a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you mount the remote server, and then an encryption layer in top of that (such as encfs or cryfs).

For example, using `encfs`:

```
mkdir /mnt/server-A
mkdir /mnt/server-A/insecure
mkdir /mnt/server-A/secure
sshfs serverA.example.com:/storage/folder /mnt/server-A/insecure
ENCFS6_CONFIG=/mnt/server-A/encfs6.xml encfs /mnt/server-A/insecure /mnt/server-A/secure
cp -v /home/SirMuffington/secret_file.txt /mnt/server-A/secure
```

`encfs` can be replaced with cryfs as a more modern alternative that fixes some of its shortcomings.

The folders are used this way:

`/mnt/server-A/insecure` provides the files in server-A, mounted locally. These are encrypted, so someone at server A would have no access to the underlying files, as they are encrypted by encfs/cryfs.

`/mnt/server-A/secure` provides the plaintext view of the files. They are actually saved (once encrypted) on `/mnt/server-A/insecure` which really is storing the files on folder `/storage/folder` of serverA.example.com.

`/mnt/server-A/encfs6.xml` Is a configuration file for encfs. It is usually stored on the encrypted folder, but here I am storing it outside.

*And that's it*. Your local computer is presumed to be trusted. Since all encryption takes place locally, there is quite little trust placed on the server (the are are some things it could do, most importantly, deleting all the files or reverting them to the state they were in some months ago).

Note that you don't need a second server, as you are not trusting the server to begin with.

Comment: Does this logic have any flaws? Like is it resistant to MitM and potentially malicious sysadmins on Server B? (if we were to use the two server scenario)